# Two worksheets with two columns and indicates match if both columns are the same

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would love some help. I have two worksheets with the same data columns, State and Email. I am attempting to cross reference if the two sheets have matching information.

EG: To verify "email@email.com" and "Texas" are in the same row in both worksheets.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, then come back and edit your question.

Comment: use COUNTIFS:  `=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B2),"Exists","Does Not Exist")`

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner I tried applying the formula you noted above 

=IF(COUNTIFS(OfficeForms.Table3[@[Your email address]],'Agent State Data'!D1455,'Agent State Data'!C1455,'Agent Responses'!F1455),"Exists","Does Not Exist")

I hope I got it correct. However if it is correct, I do notice that there are clients who have both email and location the same in both worksheets, but the response to the formula is showing "Does not exist"

Comment: You have not given us enough information to even attempt at how to fix your formula.  you have some structured references and some not.  Take a moment and familiarize yourself with [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) and maybe you can figure out what is wrong with the formula.